# Bootstrap single word textbox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

I was wondering if there is any way to make a bootstrap textbox that only accepts one word, or if not any way to show an error message if more than one word is put into the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple regexp like this `/^\w+$/` to check if the value is only one word. To check the value, bind to `onkeyup` or `onchange` event on that input:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('text');
var error = document.getElementById('error');

input.onkeyup = function() {
  if (!input.value.match(/^\w+$/)) {
    error.innerText = 'fill in only one word!';
  } else {
    error.innerText = '';
  }  
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<div id="error"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

no, there isnt.

if you want it, I would suggest you to use the keyup event and take your `event.target.value.trim().split(' ')`, if more than 1 position, then it has more than 1 word.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the value when it changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt-one').change(function() {
    if (/ /g.test($.trim(this.value))) {
      console.log('You have entered more than one word!')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt-one" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well bootstrap doesn't provide this functionality by default but you can write a small script for it. Please refer the link below, I have written a small script it should be able to give you a basic idea of implementation.

```
JS BIN Code
```

https://jsbin.com/duzevuleye/edit?html,output